# Android: Is there a way to finish a Bluetooth broadcast receiver early if a device is found?

Tags: android, bluetooth, broadcastreceiver

I have an `Android` app that needs to connected to a `Bluetooth` enabled device with a specific name/MAC. Is there any way to finish a `BroadcastReceiver` so that once the device is registered it sends signal to move 
from: 
`BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)`
to:
`BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED.equals(action)`

So that I don't have to wait until my app naturally finishes it's search?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is placing this if statement:

```
if (device.getName().equals("SOME NAME")) {
                mBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
            }
```

inside `if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action))`